# What is an easy and clean way to access vendor files from a Laravel 5 view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've installed [bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) (using bower) to my Laravel 5 project. Bootstrap-calendar got installed into my laravel/**vendor**/bootstrap-calendar/ folder.

To use bootstrap-calendar, I need to reference CSS/JS files in my views, from:

```
laravel/vendor/bootstrap-calendar/css
laravel/vendor/bootstrap-calendar/js
```

Is there an easy and clean way to use these files in my project without having to copy them to the public folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The files outside of the `public` directory are not available over HTTP (since `public` is the server's Document Root). You have two options here:

1. Copy the `bootstrap-calendar` files to your `public` directory (not the best solution, because on any update of the package you would need to copy them again)
2. Create a symbolic link from the vendor directory to a `bootstrap-calendar` directory in `public` using the following command (make sure you create the `bootstrap-calendar` directory in `public` beforehand):

```sh
ln -s /path/to/laravel/vendor/bootstrap-calendar /path/to/laravel/public/bootstrap-calendar
```

Then you can include them in your view like so:

```php
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap-calendar/css/calendar.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap-calendar/js/calendar.js') }}">
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Thanks for explaining step by step

Comment: I was using symbolic links until I read the comment about elixir; copying the files really is not the right way to achieve this, and should definitely **not** be the first option (specially when the question explicitly asks for a solution "without having to copy").

Comment: i don't think linking a file under vendor should be treated as a good practice

Comment: @Plokko Would you be so kind as to add some arguments to back up that statement, because so far it just seems to be an opinion and nothing more.

Comment: Elixir/mix approach, like in  @ceejayoz solution, is the right way to do it because:
- fist of all it will be processed by webpack with all the other resources;
- it's listed in the right place with all the other resources
- a composer update could break dependencies if an ln is used or the file will never be up-to-date if copy is used, with Elixir approach the public files are updated only after the rebuilt.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix) (known as [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir) on Laravel <= 5.3) to perform this and other functions on your app's assets.

Laravel >= 5.4:

```
mix.copy('vendor/bootstrap-calendar/css', 'public/bootstrap-calendar/css');
mix.copy('vendor/bootstrap-calendar/js', 'public/bootstrap-calendar/js');
```

Laravel <= 5.3:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('vendor/bootstrap-calendar/css', 'public/bootstrap-calendar/css');
    mix.copy('vendor/bootstrap-calendar/js', 'public/bootstrap-calendar/js');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that too. So this solution will copy the files after I add the code above to the gulpfile.js (project root directory) and run the gulp command. If I update bootstrap-calendar later, I need to rerun the gulp command to update the files copied in the public directory.

Comment: @user3489502 Correct. Typically, a Gulp run would be part of your deployment process.

Comment: I ran gulp but my files were not copied over to the public/bootstrap-calendar/ directories. So I changed the paths from 'laravel/vendor/bootstrap-calendar/css' to 'vendor/bootstrap-calendar/css'. Now it worked

Comment: The accepted answer is just a workaround. This is the real solution, using Elixir.